# Custom add-on accessing method from another custom add-on …

Tags: expresso-store, add-on-development, extension, hook

I've got a custom add-on/extension that extends the `Store` module by tapping into the `store_order_complete_end` hook to save details of an order to an XML file stored on the server.

I want to access this method from within another plugin. How best to achieve this? In Craft CMS I would abstract this method in my first plugin into a service that could then be called by another add-on. However, my EE is a bit rusty and not sure how best to achieve this in EE (EE2).

Thoughts appreciated.

Cole

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the advice provided by Brian in EECMS Slack. You can do this:

```
require_once PATH_THIRD . 'your_addon/somefile.php'
$someFile = new SomeFile();
$someFile->method();
```